# c# Expression lambda to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, expression

After using converters (Redgate, Telerik, ...) I can not turn this expression c # to vb.net

```
if (afterItemRemoved != null)
        {
            cacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback = x => afterItemRemoved(
                x.CacheItem.Key,
                (T)x.CacheItem.Value);
        }
```

I have tried without success the following expressions (Reflector 8.5 de RedGate y converter.telerik.com)

```
If (afterItemRemoved IsNot Nothing) Then
    cacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback = x => afterItemRemoved.Invoke(x.CacheItem.Key, DirectCast(x.CacheItem.Value, T))
End If


If afterItemRemoved IsNot Nothing Then
    cacheItemPolicy.RemovedCallback = Function(x) afterItemRemoved(x.CacheItem.Key, DirectCast(x.CacheItem.Value, T))
End If
```

Comment: what you have tried looks completely different from the original one. why the function names are different in your attempt?

Comment: are two similar methods, is a transcription error. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: A tool converting "!=" (C#) into ">" (VB.NET) is certainly not too useful.

Comment: It's weird, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [RemovedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.removedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we can see that the required delegate signature is a `void` method (A `Sub` in VB.Net) (see [CacheEntryRemovedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheentryremovedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So the lambda expression needed has to be a "Sub Lambda" not a "Function lambda"

```
If afterItemRemoved IsNot Nothing Then
    cacheItemPolicy.RemoveCallback =
        Sub(x) afterItemRemoved(x.CacheItem.Key, DirectCast(x.CacheItem.Value, T))
End If
```